# Encoding value in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON "rows" that contains an address element.  I want to encode the address element in order to remove a "/" which gives me an error as the rest service treats it as a part of a url.  i've tried a few things but can't seem to get the address element from the JSON encode it and replace it in the JSON.  Any idea how to go about this?

What i've tried:

```
tempAddress = JSON.stringify(rows[i].address;
encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(tempAddress);
rows[i].address = JSON.parse(encodedAddress);

next attempt:

rows[i].address = JSON.parse(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(rows[i].address)));
```

Comment: Syntax: closing parenthesis missing on first line. Did you actually run this code? Could you please provide sample data for `row[i]`? What exactly goes wrong? Error message? At which step you get an unexpected result, and what is it, and what should it be?

Comment: Why are you *parsing* the result? If you're sending this somewhere, you would serialize and **they** would parse.

Comment: No this is just an example of what i've done

Comment: We really need more context to be able to help. Fundamentally, `encodeURIComponent` is how you do this. (You just need to actually *use* that rather than reparsing.)

Comment: Note that the inverse operation of `y = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(x))` would be `x = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(y))`, not just `x = JSON.parse(y)`

Answer (score 0):

your object row is view as an object in javascript you can set the property as you set javascript object property. only

```
rows[i].address = encodedAddress;
```

is necessary to encode the adress in your object.

when you will want to decode the adress in your json object you will be abble to do this by using :

```
adress = decodeURIComponent(rows[i].address)
```